# Swift Get UIImage from layers of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, calayer

I have CAShapeLayers in my UIView and I want UIImage from the view.
So I am trying thru below function but getting an error at
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

```
extension UIView
{
    func getImgFromVyuFnc() -> UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)

        self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2017-08-17 04:17:47.230474 PicPac[1095:488887] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: The most likely issue is that `self.frame.size` is zero in one or both dimension(s).

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Posted as answer now. Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size passed to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_)` is zero in either or both dimension(s) then `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns `nil` and so will `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`.

Comment: Thanks your hint and Setting frame size worked for me. Can u consider voting up for my questions too? So it wil come up and help others also who face problem like me.